# Weird behaviour querySelector

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have component in angular

in component.ts i have line of code that serach html element

```
var myArticle = document.querySelector('article');
```

this return null

in component.html

```
<article id="bodyArticle" *ngIf="isClicked"></article>
```

but when I use article in sibling component.ts

```
var myArticle != null from component.ts
```

How it's work querySelector serach element in all file project ?

I also have other problem. In same componen.html i have button

```
<div class="btnGrp">
  <button (click)="loadXML($event)">Load</button>
  <input type="file" name="img" multiple (change)="onChange($event)">
</div>
<article id="bodyArticle" *ngIf="isClicked"></article>
```

When i click button one click emitted is value true firstly and i must click second to button to load thata to article content

snippet from component.ts

```
  loadXML(event?: Event) {
    var myArticle = document.querySelector('article');
    console.log(myArticle);
    if(this.imageService.getBodyRes() == ''){
      myArticle.textContent = 'Error can't load data';
      this.isClicked = true;
      this.xmlLoadedEvent.emit(this.isClicked);
    } else {
      myArticle.textContent = this.imageService.getBodyRes();
      console.log(myArticle.textContent);
      this.isClicked = true;
      this.xmlLoadedEvent.emit(this.isClicked);
    }
  }
```

How to do that when i click button in article tag ngIf set true value and also loadData without dobule click.

Comment: We'll need a little more description than that. I believe you are calling the selector before the component is mounted to DOM.

Comment: @squgeim i think mistake is that isclicked = false and element is not render yet and return null value

Comment: if your sibling component <app-abc> is loaded after article, then that is the issue

Comment: when are u calling your method, `isClicked` must be true, is it ?

Comment: open ur console and run `document.querySelector('article');` to see if it returns null or not

Comment: @Milad one for my mistake is that i set isClicked to false

Comment: that's it then, make it true before accessing the element , otherwise it's not gonna be created by Angular

Comment: Milad I would do that this element is invisible after view render. I want display this element only when i click to button. How to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to avoid using the document object and its methods in Angular. It will make your life very difficult if you try to do that.

```
 <article #articleId id="bodyArticle" *ngIf="isClicked"></article>
```

You can put a template variable name on the article tag, and then query it with angular's 'ViewChild' class like so -

```
 import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef,  ...others?....} from '@angular/core'

export class MyComponent {

   articleToggle: boolean = false; // add a toggle in your component for turning the article on 

   @ViewChild('articleId') article: ElementRef;

   ngAfterViewInit() {
       this.article.nativeElement.<<access DOM attributes here>>
   }
}
```

This will give you access to the DOM node, like you expected your document query to have done, but even so, there are probably still better ways to do what you are doing, especially since you mentioned you are trying to use the article in sibling components. If that is the case, you may want to make it its own component allowing you to avoid queries altogether, but again, impossible to know with so little info.

Also, its generally recommended to avoid comparing to null entirely in typescript. Use 'undefined' instead.

```
<button (click)="loadXML($event); articleToggle = true">Load</button>
```

Set your variable to true on click, and then for the article.

```
<article #articleId id="bodyArticle" *ngIf="articleToggle"></article>
```

Now it will appear after the first click of the button, as that will be the only time the value changes from false -> true.

Comment: firstly i set isClicked to false. Now i change to true but I would that this element is invisible after render view. How to do that that this article become visible after clicked in button item.

Comment: I also have problem that i must clcik double to button firstly load empty article and when i second click then executed method loadXML that loaded content. Maybe you know how avoid this ? I would click only one time render article with content

Comment: that behavior should be eliminated if you define and set the 'articleToggled' boolean as i showed instead of using the isClicked one. You could toss that, or just switch the names of them. B